# System of linear inequalities - mixture

Tags: inequality

I have a problem and I couldn't find a solution yet (and the method which way I can achieve the solution).

Example:

We have 4 types bottles of water.
Bottle 1 - with capacity 750ml - we have 2 for use with price 0,25
Bottle 2 - with capacity 500ml - we have 3 for use with price 0,5
Bottle 3 - with capacity 250ml - we have 5 for use with price 0,75
Bottle 4 - with capacity 100ml - we have 10 for use with price 1

Using water from these 4 types of bottles we have to create "aqueous mixture" containing 3050ml of water in total.

How we should pour water from those bottles that cost as low as possible and to have the least possible loss of water.

How to solve this?
I was wondering about Symplex method, but I can't find good assumptions that I can contiune counting.

Can anyone have any ideas how to achieve this? I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) -  Note that while the naive solution is exponential, programming the solution with some intelligence (that is, by using "dynamic programming" - i.e, solving it bottom up while using memoization) will give you a polynomial-time algorithm